# Differently-formatted issuerUserId when using Microsoft Account provider in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We're investigating a migration of our existing authentication system to Azure AD B2C. Our current system accepts both MSA and Google logins, and we use an in-house developed service based on IdentityServer, which stores the IDs from the third-party IdPs in Azure Table storage.

I've followed the instructions for [setting up MSA as an ID provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-msa-app) and for [migrating users with a social account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-social-migration), and have converted my existing MSA IDs to base64 when posting them as userIdentities to the AD Graph API (in line with the sample code from the second link above). But when I sign in with an MSA, instead of recognizing my account, it directs me to the sign-up page (as part of the Sign-in/Sign-up policy I have defined).

If I follow through with creating the user, and then inspect the newly created user with the `/users/<new-user-id>` endpoint in the Graph API, I get back a strange-looking issuerUserId when compared to what I have stored for my Microsoft users currently.

My existing users have ids that look something like `1234ab56789cde01`, and the IDs being sent to me via B2C are formatted as something like `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbCdEF12GhIj_KlM34nOPQ`when base64 decoded. (Values altered to avoid any potential privacy issues.) The capital 'A's are always there at the beginning, and I get characters from the full range of alphanumeric values in the new format as compared to the original IDs that only have a range of hexadecimal characters.

I've managed to get the Google accounts working just fine. All that's necessary there is to convert them to base64 and they just work. But I'm struggling to figure out how to migrate the MSAs. Either I'm doing something wrong on the app registration side, or there's another step to generating the `AAAAAAAA`-prefixed IDs that I'm just missing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Azure AD B2C is saving the *subject* claim that is issued for the Microsoft account to the *userIdentity* object. Are you referencing the same claim? Also, I believe the *subject* claim is a pairwise identifier, i.e. it is unique to a particular application.

Comment: I was worried it was an app-specific ID, since it means that the migration won't be quite as smooth as I'd have liked. We're currently using the [Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount package](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount) to pull the IDs. The sub claim I get from that seems to match the ID I get when I query the MS Graph API outside the scope of our specific app's client id/secret. After reading the docs for the v2 endpoints, it appears what I'm really after is the oid instead of the sub claim this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in identity provider for Microsoft Account maps from the **sub** (subject) claim for the Microsoft account to the **issuerUserId** property of the **userIdentity** object.

If you are wanting to migrate identities that are mapped from a different claim (such as the **oid** (object identifier) claim) of a Microsoft account, then you must [use custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) and then [add a custom identity provider for Microsoft Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-msa-idp) with the following modification:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
    <Domain>live.com</Domain>
    <DisplayName>Microsoft Account</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="MSA-OIDC">
            <DisplayName>Microsoft Account</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
            <Metadata>
                <Item Key="ProviderName">https://login.live.com</Item>
                <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.live.com/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
                <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
                <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
                <Item Key="scope">openid profile email</Item>
                <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
                <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
                <Item Key="client_id">Your Microsoft application client id</Item>
            </Metadata>
            <CryptographicKeys>
                <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_MSASecret" />
            </CryptographicKeys>
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="live.com" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
                <!-- ORIGINAL: The following output claims maps from the "sub" claim to the "issuerUserId" property. -->
                <!--<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />-->
                <!-- MODIFICATION: The following output claims maps from the "oid" claim to the "issuerUserId" property. -->
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
            </OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
    </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

For information about getting started with custom policies, see [Azure Active Directory B2C: Get started with custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom).

Comment: That got it. Thanks so much! I hadn't even considered using custom policy for one of the built-in providers. The only issue I see now is that the ids are coming in formatted as guids (our existing ones don't seem to be full guids), but that's easy to overcome by simply applying some formatting in our migration. Thanks again!